# Obtener App ID de Firebase

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una app en Android conjuntamente con Firebase. Y en la consola de Firebase en la sección Configuración del proyecto me sale una App ID. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo obtener esa ID pero desde mi aplicación en Android?
Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo logré, lo hice así:

```
// declaro la variable
public static FirebaseApp fbApp;
...
// obtengo la instancia
fbApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
...
//asigno el valor 
lblClave.setText(fbApp.getOptions().getApplicationId());
```